# Track goals in ajax request with google analytics ga.js

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I try to track a goal in an ajax request but its not working. This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://domain.com",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            crossDomain: true,
            data: $("#registrationForm").serialize(),
            success: function(data)
            {
                if(data.message == "ok") {

                    if(data.subscription == 16801 || data.subscription == 17001) {

                        if(data.subscription == 16801) {
                            var url = "/product/premium";
                        } else {
                            var url = "/product/basic";
                        }

                        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
                        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'XX-XXXXXX-X']);
                        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', url]);

                        (function() {
                          var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                          ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                          var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
                        })();
                    }

                }
            }
      });
```

Any idea what I do wrong? The script is working perfectly except for setting the goal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of goal are you setting, and how it is configured (screen shots, please)? Not sure what you mean by everything working "except for setting the goal". The goal isn't set in the code, it's configured in GA.

Comment: If by "setting the goal" you mean "sending the virtual pageview" you should check if you use the correct version of the tracking code (and if you do you should upgrade to the current code. And if your page already includes a tracker you should not create a new one because that breaks the GA sessions). But I agree with nyuen that the question is not quite clear enough (e.g. do "/product" urls show in Analytics but there is no goal conversion, or is nothing sent to GA ?).

Comment: @EikePierstorff  I mean sending the virtual pageview. I discovered I already included a tracker so I removed the function that included the ga.js. The problem is that de page is not tracked at all.

Comment: I did not mean the bit that includes the ga.js, I mean the _setAccount call. That creates a new tracker and effectively interrupts the GA session.  If you have set the account previously you do need to repeat it here.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will remove the setAccount and try it again.

Comment: I removed the SetAccount line but it isnt working. What I do to test is to look on the realtime dashboard in analytics and check the source page. I see that it's changing when I move to another page. But when I create the account (ajax request) the pageview/source page product/basic is not set. (source is still the last page I visit)

Comment: I fixed it. The only thing I had to use was this line _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', url]);